# How to calculate margin of error for a binomial quality control experiment where only successes are observed (including FPC)?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, measurement-error, quality-control

Wikipedia's *Margin of Error* entry says that

> a random sample of size 400 will give a margin of error, at a 95%
>   confidence level, of 0.98/20 or 0.049 - just under 5%

given an infinite population size. This means that if I polled 400 US citizens (randomly selected) and asked them "Obama or Romney?", the resulting proportion would be accurate with a 95% confidence level, to a margin of error below 5%.

However, can I use this same calculation in testing that a software program will be able to deal with roughly all inputs?

For example: I have an infinite population of users, I need to be sure (95% confident, given 5% error) that my software will be able to come up with a nickname for all of them based on their name and a simple algorithm.

If I randomly select 400 users, and the nickname algorithm works perfectly for all 400 users, can I assume (with 95% confidence, given 5% error) that my algorithm holds for the entire population? Is this the incorrect way to calculate margin of error for this type of problem?

Comment: First, the margin of error given in the wiki article was based on a binary outcome with a 50/50 chance of success, which would have the maximal margin of error - so the margin of error is at most 0.049 - this same logic applies for any binary outcome, not just poll results. Second, are you asking that if you sampled 400 people and the algorithm worked for all 400 people, can you conclude that the algorithm would work for 100% of the population? That seems to be a different question.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking that if I sampled 400 people, and the algorithm worked for 100%, can I conclude with 95% confidence that it will work for 100% of the population?

Comment: If this question is different, what search terms can I use to find the answer to this question?

Comment: I have looked at the "Sample Size Determination" Wikipedia entry (along with "Statistical Significance", "Statistical Power", "Sampling", and "P-value"), however these all seem to discuss 50/50 political candidate-style surveys (or types of distributions) and not pass/fail testing-surveys

Comment: The short answer is 'No'. One problem is that the normal approximation used to generate that margin of error is not valid when the outcome has a 100% (or 0%) chance of success - see the normal approximation part of  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval

Comment: I've changed the question title to reflect better the question and eventual answer and increase the chance of someone else who needs to know coming across it - hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0.049 calculation from Wikipedia only applies if the probability of success is 0.5 ($1.96\times\sqrt{\frac{0.5\times0.5}{400}}$).  This isn't the case in your situation; but the good news is that as probability of success gets closer to zero or one the margin of error for any particular sample size gets smaller.

You are interested in estimating the probability of success (let's call it $p$) and in particular a 95 percent confidence interval for it.

The chance of seeing no failures in $n$ experiments is $p^n$ so for example if you set 0.99 as a possible value of $p$ the chance of seeing 400 successes is only $0.99^{400}=0.017$.  This is pretty small so normally we would say that this is evidence against p being as low as 0.99, whereas it is perfectly consistent with p=1 which is what you want.  But p could still plausibly be as high as (for example) 0.999 - because 67% of the time, if p=0.999, 400 random trials will all be successes, even though this might be unacceptably low success rate for your overall population.

To cut a long story short, if you have a run of successes you can estimate a 95 percent confidence interval with ($e^{(\frac{log(0.05)}{n})}, 1]$.  So if you plug the value of n=400 into this (because you had 400 successes) you find the confidence interval is (0.9925, 1].  It is up to you to determine whether a rate of success that could plausibly be as low 0.9925 is good enough for your purposes.

**EDIT - addition on finite population**

In my comments I noted that the above formula for the lower bound of the confidence interval came from solving $0.05=p^n$ for $p$.  If you have a finite population you have the more complex challenge of solving the equation below for p:

$0.05=\frac{Np}{N}\times \frac{Np-1}{N-1}\times ... \frac{Np-n+1}{N-n+1}$

There may be a solution to this but I found it easier to write a function in R that does it for me iteratively, and returns an interval of (0.9945, 1] if you have 400 trials out of a finite population of 1000.  The function test() below can be used for any combination of number of trials and population size.

```
tmp <- function(N,n,p){
    x <- 1
    f <- round(N*p)
    for (i in 0:(n-1)){
        x <- x * (f-i) / (N-i)
    }
x
}

test <- function(N,n){
    p <- exp(log(0.05)/n) # start with infinite N
    incr <- n/N * 0.00001
    x <- tmp(N, n,p)
    while(x <0.05){
    x <- tmp(N, n,p)
    p <- p + incr
    }
p
}

> test(10^10,400)
[1] 0.9925386
> test(1000,400)
[1] 0.9945066
> test(450,400)
[1] 0.9966809
```

Comment: Where does the interval $(e^{(\frac{log(0.05)}{n})}, 1]$ come from?

Comment: I'm looking for a value of p that will generate n successes with probability x=0.05.  Values of p below that are not in the confidence interval because 95% or more of the time you will not see n successes.  Solve x=p^n; log(x)=n.log(p); p=exp(log(x)/n).  1 is obviously in the interval because it is the maximum likelihood estimate after n successes; and is also the upper bound allowable for the parameter p.

Comment: to be in the interval it is *at least* .05, yes; but the lower bound of the interval is where it is *exactly* .05.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the clarification. This is a very slick answer that I certainly wouldn't have thought of - very nice.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, that's a great answer.  One quick follow-up, could you comment on how the "finite population correction" would factor into your equation for confidence interval?  I assume that would alter the 0.05 number in your equation?

Comment: Thanks @Macro.  Sam re finite population - no, quite a bit more complicated, see my addition to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing or can do is generate a 95% exact confidence interval for the proportion in the population that will properly generate a nickname.  The interval you get when there are only successes will be [p, 1].  You can interpret this to mean that this procedure when taking a sample of size 400 repeatedly will include the true proportion approximately 95% of the time or more.  So you have strong confidence to think that the proportion is greater than p.